# Как выделить активную рубрику(категорию)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, вёрстка

У меня в меню не только страницы, но и рубрики. Активные страницы выделяются цветом, а рубрики - нет. Подскажите, как выделять и рубрики тоже?

Comment: Так же, как и выделяете активные страницы. (*Задавайте глупые вопросы, получайте умные ответы*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в теме используется wp_nav_menu. К активному пункту меню присваивается класс current-menu-item. Дайте стили для данного класса в файле css